# How to GetGuiResources for all system processes?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, managed-c++

I need to measure all used GDI objects in a Windows xp system. I found a GetGuiResources(__in  HANDLE hProcess,  __in  DWORD uiFlags) method (with the GR_GDIOBJECTS flag). I call it for the process which I get from the method GetCurrentProcess() defined in WinBase.h.

I don't know how to call it for other system processes, which I get by System::Diagnostics::Process::GetProcesses(), because that function returns an array of Process pointers, and GetGuiResources takes a HANDLE.

Does anybody know a solution for that? How can I transform Process pointer to a Handle or get HANDLEs for all running system processes?

thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Yes, I had to set /clr:oldSyntax in VisualStudio, because the code wouldn't compile without that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) property of each Process object of the array returned by GetProcesses() you can get the ID of each process. Then, from an ID, you can get a handle via the [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28VS.85%29.aspx) API. Remember to close the handle with [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) when you don't need it anymore.

Note that you **can't** use the [Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.handle%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) property of the Process objects, because it works only for the objects returned by Process.Start.

By the way, keep in mind that for new projects you should use the new C++/CLI language instead of the old Managed C++ extensions.