# VBA: GDI and User Objects

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a macro for Excel (2007/2010) which gathers information about the process and displays it within specified cells. So far I cannot get the GDI/User objects, but I can get the handle etc.

I use this to get the process:

```
Set oServ = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Set cProc = oServ.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
```

I then find the process i am looking for and grab Peak Working Set memory, Handles, etc. I have tried using GetGuiResources to grab GDI/User Objects but I cannot get it to work for a specified process (returns 0). I read a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494221/how-to-getguiresources-for-all-system-processes) where it said to use OpenProcess, but that doesn't work either.

```
Range(CStr(Cell_Holder)).Value = GetGuiResources(jProc.Handle, 0) 'jProc is the process wanted

Range(CStr(Cell_Holder)).Value = GetGuiResources(GetCurrentProcess, 0)' this works...
```

Comment: Did you try using the ID instead of `jProc`?

Comment: @Tom I tried using jProc.ProcessId before but it didn't work either. I'm stumped on what i should do.

Comment: Did you check if there are any GUI objects in use? And do you get any other errors? Or is it just the return 0?

Comment: @Tom Yeah there are GDI/User objects that are being used. There are no errors as far as I know. The only return i get is 0 for those values. When I try to use the GetCurrentProcess function it returns the correct values (although this is not the process wanted).

Comment: sorry, but I cant see anything wrong. :/ Could you post some more code? Or is this all there is?

Answer (score 0):

Since the WMI-Query returns a `Win32_Process` object but the `GetGuiResources` requires a `hWND` (window handle), you have to get the handle from the Win32_Process. Unfortunately this is **not** the `Handle` member of the Win32_Process.

You could use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to get the required window handle. In C#, you would do the following:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;

const int GR_GDIOBJECTS = 0;

// ...

String wmiQuery = "select * from Win32_Process";
ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection processList = search.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
{
    int pid = (int)(uint)obj["ProcessId"];
    Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
    String name = p.ProcessName;
    try
    {
        int handleCount = GetGuiResources(p.Handle, GR_GDIOBJECTS);
        Console.WriteLine(name + ": " + handleCount);
    }
    catch 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name + ": Access denied");
    }
}
```